# modernizr slows down tablesorter

Tags: javascript, tablesorter, modernizr

I'm using a template (Developr) which utilizes Modernizr. Also I use Tablesorter plugin.
The thing is, if I disable Modernizr, sorting a table (2k+ rows) takes around 3 seconds. But template features don't work. With Modernizr enabled, sorting the same table takes more than 1 minute!
Is there any way to speed up the process? (ie somehow prohibit tablesorter-modernizr interaction etc). Using latest versions of both plugins - Modernizr v2.7.1, Tablesorter v2.14.3

P.S. Sorting a table with 100 rows takes about same time no matter Modernizr is on or off (at least visually)

P.S.2 Even MouseOver (it is supposed to highlight a row in a table) on 2k rows table works with a noticable delay.

Timelines from Chrome:

Modernizr ON: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lurhmx3w7esi304/TimelineRawData-20131204T202607.json

Modernizr OFF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0o648nfij9pqnl/TimelineRawData-20131204T205035.json

```
<script src="js/libs/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

<script src="js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets-filter-formatter.js"></script>
<script src="js/ts/js/jquery.metadata.js"></script>

<script id="js">$(function(){

$("#thetable").tablesorter({
  showProcessing: true,
  theme : 'green',
  widthFixed : true,
  widgets: [ 'reorder', 'zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter' ],
  widgetOptions: {
  stickyHeaders : 'tablesorter-stickyHeader',
  stickyHeaders_cloneId : '-sticky',
  stickyHeaders_offset : 35,
  filter_startsWith : true,
  filter_searchDelay : 1000,
  zebra   : ["ui-widget-content even", "ui-state-default odd"],
  uitheme : 'green',
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: Chrome, IE 11, Firefox...

Comment: First step to debugging in chrome would be to record a timeline in chrome during the period that is taking forever (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline#tips_for_making_recordings). That should show you where the slowness is. It will be hard for anyone to assist you without live code - could you put it up on jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: here is a link to timeline from chrome - https://www.dropbox.com/s/lurhmx3w7esi304/TimelineRawData-20131204T202607.json Will try to put code to jsfiddle

Comment: And this is a timeline from chrome, when modernizr is disabled. Sorting same table/same column. https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0o648nfij9pqnl/TimelineRawData-20131204T205035.json

Comment: The issue is you are triggering a CRAZY amount of v8 garbage collector calls during that minute. More than likely you are teating towards the edge of some v8 GC opt, and modernizr just happens to be pushing you over it. Try taking heap snapshots of the page (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling) to see if we can track down the source of the garbage

Comment: Here is heap snapshot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6kj90b9sxl4lan/Heap-20131204T231406.heapsnapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick! Thank you very much for your help. Your tips led me to solution. 
Problem was in additional script, which was run by template. DOM changes watcher was set to true. So, when tablesorter was sorting table's rows one by one, that watcher was triggered every time - that's why so much garbage was there. Turning watcher to false solved the problem.